# XBL Tabbrowser?

Tags: xul, xbl

Is there some sort of tabbrowser implementation out there in XBL (eXtensive Binding Language) for use with XUL (XML UI Language)? I haven't been able to find one so far, and need one for the project that I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

The existing `tabbrowser` implementations are very application-specific. So while you are free to use the [Firefox](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/df526497d949/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml) or [SeaMonkey](http://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/599146070d4c/suite/browser/tabbrowser.xml) implementation, these are everything but generic components. Most likely, they won't give you more than a starting point that you will have to adjust to your needs.